Windows switching to Chinese (skip weird "英" English-in-Chinese mode?)

Before (usual English mode):



When I hit Win+Spacebar, I've set it up so that it should to switch to Chinese. But instead, it often switches to this (英, some weird English in Chinese mode):



I then have to click on the "英" for it to switch properly to 中 (Chinese mode):


(Hitting Win+Spacebar switches me back to the usual English mode.)
What do I have to do so that when I hit Win+Spacebar, I immediately switch properly to 中 (Chinese mode) without my having to click on the "英"?
(And what on earth is the purpose of this weird "英" English-in-Chinese mode? Can I just delete/get rid of it completely?)
I'm using


Response to Ashish: I only have two languages:


We are unfamiliar with what it’s supposed to look like or why it’s wrong. You’ll have to do a better job explaining

it's not weird at all, all CJK IMEs have that, because you still need to enter Latin characters while typing other languages. Switching to another IME takes time, switching language in the same IME is much faster, and doesn't require the person to know English to install English keyboard

英 means English mode within the Chinese IME, allowing one to type a Chinese word in English and then select the right one. This is useful when you are using a English keyboard, and wish to type in Chinese.
You need to go to Windows settings > Time and Language > Language. Check if you have more than the required number of languages. For example, if you have three and only need two, you need to remove what is not required. That will allow you to switch instantly.
Windows Language Settings
If you don't want to uninstall, you can move up the language to instantly switch when you press Win + spacebar.

I only have two languages (see above added image)
